# The relationship between the knot group and the quandle cocycle invariant

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

Suppose the quandle cocycle invariant of a knot belongs to $\mathbb{Z}$. Does this mean that the knot group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: As in, does this mean the knot is the unknot?